# Is MIN_PEERS_TO_START_WARP_SYNC=3 for a security reason?

Tags: warp

We have observed that we need a minimum of 3 peers to start the warp sync process, and we realized it is due to this constant defined in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d38d176b844aab1338ce79eb71cd6df86c97d4a0/client/network/sync/src/lib.rs#L141-L142.

Is there a reason to set this to 3? Could this be configurable to less or more? AFAIK the warp sync process already verifies the state against the relay-chain storage-values, so this should not be malleable even if we set this value to 1 right?